# Unexpected end when reading JSON. Path '', line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm making a Minecraft account checker with a config system. (Note that the checker is made in C# and I'm using Newtonsoft.json for the config system).
So, I made a List :

```
List<string> config = File.ReadAllLines("config.json").ToList();
```

And I made a Parrallel.ForEach with that code inside :

```
Parallel.ForEach(config, things =>
        {
            dynamic configJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(things);

            int threads = (int)configJson.threads;
            string proxiesType = (string)configJson.proxiesType;

            Console.WriteLine(threads + " - " + proxiesType);
        });
```

The config.json file is pretty simple :

```
{
   "threads": 200,
   "proxiesType": "SOCKS5"
}
```

But when I run the project, I get this error :

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : 'Unexpected end when reading JSON. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

I just need help because I searched but none has solved this problem.

Comment: Postfixing `[SOLVED]` in question title is bad. Instead click on check mark (✓) on one the answers below to mark it as answer. If you solved the problem yourself, post solution as answer below and click on check mark (✓).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you're approaching it this way. There is no reason to use `Parallel.ForEach` to parse JSON.

What you're doing right now is pulling each line of your JSON file in to the list, then trying to parse each line.

So it tries to parse line 1, which is `{`. `{` is not a valid JSON object. The parsing fails.

Use `File.ReadAllText` to read the entire file into a single string, then parse the string. There is no need for any sort of looping.

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways to work with JSON files using Json.NET:

1. Using `File.ReadAllText()` as suggested by Daniel.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("config.json");
Config config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(json);
```

2. Using stream opened directly on the file. Here's how:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("config.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Config config = (Config)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Config));
}
```